# Always allow a program to act as a server

Tags: windows, firewall

I'm coding some small application. Basically it listens for incoming tcp connections.
I always get this screen:

[image]

I always press the accept/allow button but it keeps asking every time I start the program.

What can I do to let windows remember?

The app should never be blocked by the firewall.

I already created a rule to always allow it in the windows firewall settings but it asks anyway.

What can I do?

Comment: Try creating a firewall exception for this which works for all programs on your port. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh168549%28v=nav.71%29.aspx Your application should work fine once it is published, the problem the firewall is most likely having is that the sig is changing every time you recompile it so the firewall doesn't recognize it anymore and needs to ask again each time.

Comment: I created a exception that always allows all programs on that port. Still doesn't work. You said that the sig changes all the time. That makes sense to me but even when I start the exe from the debug folder multiple times it asks every time.